# Bash on Windows / Windows Subsytem for Linux (WSL) not installing correctly / hangs

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

I got the windows anniversary update and tried to install Bash. I ran bash from the command prompt (non-admin mode) and it got stuck while trying to extract the files. I closed the window and tried to do the same with elevated privileges (command prompt *run as admin*).

But now when I enter bash, it is stuck there and doesn't launch or ask me to install bash. I could see bash process consuming 25% of CPU in the background.

When I try to uninstall bash running `lxrun /uninstall /full`, it fails to uninstall:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>lxrun /uninstall /full
> This will uninstall Ubuntu on Windows.
>
> This will remove the Ubuntu environment as well as any modifications, new applications, and user data.
>
> Type "y" to continue: y
>
> Uninstalling...
>
> Error: 0x80080005

How could I reset the Linux subsystem for windows 10?

**EDIT**: Also tried options mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq) by Microsoft.

Also, check out this issue. [Bash does nothing for a while then exits](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/751)

Comment: How long did you actually wait for it to (un)install?

Comment: I waited for about 30 mins.

Comment: Alternatively you could go to *Enable or disable Windows features* and uncheck *Windows subsystem for Linux (Beta)* and then restart. After that, reenable the same checkbox and restart again. On my machine, I could not run `lxrun`.

Comment: I tried all that! I think this is a widely reported [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/718)

Comment: @VivekVijayan - Take ownership of `%localappdata%\lxss` then delete it.  You can then use `lxrun /install` to install `Ubuntu on Windows` again.  This assumes you have developer mode enabled and have already added the (Windows Linux Subsystem) Windows Feature.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I was able to remove the folder but now when I try `lxrun /install` it gets stuck exactly at the same place as before - trying to extract the files. But looking at the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\lxss\rootfs` the files seems to have extracted correctly as mentioned [here](https://www.slightfuture.com/technote/lxss-lxrun). But it fails to finish the installation for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I initially had problems *uninstalling* a failed install and removing the lxss folder. After I successfully cleaned up the installation, I began my trials to reinstall, but the earlier problem with installing popped up. The process gets stuck *Extracting Filesystem...* as reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/772).

After days of trial and error, I seem to have found the reason for this agony. In my case (and as reported by many others [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/772)) it is the antivirus being the spoilsport. Disabling antivirus and restarting seem to do it for me.
As silly as it sounds, Antivirus was the main cause for the pain and `Error: 0x80080005`

Now for those who still have this error, this is should help if you try doing the following things in order:

1. Disable Antivirus permanently & Restart (You can enable it after the installation is complete)
2. Open *Command Prompt* or *Windows PowerShell* as **admin**
3. Uninstall WSL by running the following command `lxrun /uninstall /full`
4. Now stop WSL service - `sc stop lxssmanager`
5. Remove App data folders - `rmdir /S %LOCALAPPDATA%\lxss`. Confirm the folders have been deleted. You might need to change the ownership to delete the folder if you get any *access-denied* errors.
6. Once the folders are deleted, try installing WSL again by running `lxrun /install /y`
7. Wait until it downloads from the Windows Store and Extracts the files. (You can check `%LOCALAPPDATA%\lxss\rootfs` to see if the files have been extracted).
8. Hopefully you **shouldn't** get a `Error: 0x80080005` this time.
9. Enjoy **Bash on Windows**!

**EDIT** : Another reason for the error is identified as a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/538%20here) when you have **multiple swap files**. This will be fixed in the future, but for now, remove other swap files and keep only one swapfile. This should fix it.

More details for those interested:

"*Because of your trace file I have identified a bug in the installation code that is calculating the swap file size. This function is used by both the sysinfo system call and generating the contents of /proc/meminfo. This problem will happen when you have multiple pagefiles on your machine. There are three different outcomes that can happen as a result of this bug:
The swapfile size will be reported incorrectly
Our driver will dereference an invalid memory address and cause a bluescreen
The machine will enter an infinite loop when calculating the swap file size (this is the one you are seeing)
As a temporary workaround if you remove all but one of your pagefiles you should be able to use WSL. I am coding up a fix for this right now.*"

Reference: [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#how-do-i-fully-uninstall-wsl)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.   I had Windows Defender running and I only had to do 1-3 and 6-9, i.e. I didn't have to stop the service or delete anything.

Comment: Happy to help. In some cases, WSL service hinders the clean removal of installation files. Glad you didn't have to go through all that.